# How to hide navigation header after adding in nested screens react-native

Tags: react-native

**I have Main screen in which there is a headerbar also this screen contain 2 tabs name Home and Settings , these two tabs have their own header bar their is a button inside my Home Screen which when click calls Details Screen from this Detail Screen i want to hide Main Screen header bar**

**Code for MainScreen HeaderBar**

```
const TabScreen = createStackNavigator({
TabScreen: {
screen: RootStack,
navigationOptions: {
  headerTitle: 'Tabs'
},
},
});
```

**Code For Tabs**

```
const RootStack = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
{
Home: {
  screen: HomeRoot,
  navigationOptions : {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    tabBarIcon:  <Image source={{uri: 
'https://png.icons8.com/Home/ultraviolet/50/3498db'}} style={{width:20, 
height: 20}}/>
  },
},
Settings: {
  screen: Settings,
  navigationOptions : {
    tabBarLabel: 'Setting',
    tabBarIcon:  <Image source={{uri: 
 'https://png.icons8.com/Home/ultraviolet/50/3498db'}} style= . 
 {{width:20, height: 20}}/>
  },     
},
},
```

**Code for Home and Details Screen**

```
const HomeRoot = createStackNavigator(
{
Home: {
  screen: Home,
},  
Details: {
  screen: Details,
}, 

},
{
initialRouteName: 'Home',
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
headerMode: 'none',
```

Comment: i use this but  in my case In MainScreen i have to show Headerbar and In the Home tab when i click button and go to details class i want to hide it their but it didn't happened. I know headerMode: 'none' hide headerbar but i have to show it in mainscreen than hide it